Top-Down 3rd person shooter player didn't move accordingly to world axis
I'm working on my microgame project, which involved top-down 3rd-person shooter movement. A picture would be easier to explain.

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

public class EntityController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [SerializeField] private float maxAccelTime = 2;
    [SerializeField] private Camera currentCam;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D currentPlayer;

    private Vector2 cursorPos;
    private Vector2 lookDir;
    private float lookAngle;

    private float accelTime, accelMultipier;
    private float dragMultipier;
    
    void Start()
    {
        accelTime = 0;
        accelMultipier = 15;
        dragMultipier = 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Control Movement Button
        MovementController();
        //Control Attack Button
        AttackController();
    }
    private void MovementController()
    {
        //Control speed of the player. Player will get faster as long as they pressing the button and not stop moving immediately when stop pressing.
        InitiateAceleration();
        //Control look direction and movement of the player.
        InitiateMovement();
    }
    private void AttackController()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Initiate Attack on Mouse Direction
        }
    }
    private void InitiateMovement()
    {
        //Control look direction of the player.
        cursorPos = currentCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        lookDir = cursorPos - currentPlayer.position;
        lookAngle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;

        //Control movement direction of the player.
        currentPlayer.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * accelTime * accelMultipier * Time.deltaTime);
        currentPlayer.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * accelTime * accelMultipier * Time.deltaTime);

        currentPlayer.rotation = lookAngle;
    }
    private void InitiateAceleration()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            if (accelTime < maxAccelTime)
            {
                accelTime += Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (accelTime > 0)
            {
                accelTime -= (Time.deltaTime * dragMultipier);
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to make a condition that if lookDir.x > 0 and lookDir.y > 0, the player will move (I thought that the shakiness was from a positional problem when the player moves really close to the cursor). Dosen't work.

Transform.Translate has an optional last parameter Space relativeTo which by default moves in local space (Space.Self)!
In order to apply the translation in world space you need to pass in Space.World as additional last parameter.

In general though you shouldn't move a Rigidbody2D through the transform at all but rather go through MovePosition which correctly checks and handles collitions. Here you would directly pass in a new world space position
var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
// optionally clamp for diagonal movement 
input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(input, 1f);
var movement = input * accelTime * accelMultipier * Time.deltaTime;
currentPlayer.MovePosition(currentPlayer.position + movement);

